# NetLogo: moving turtle until it finds the final patch in 1 tick?

Tags: debugging, while-loop, netlogo, repeat, do-while

I would like to let my turtle wander until its `energy` level `< [totalattract] of patch-here`. The code here works fine:

```
to move-turtles
  ifelse ([totalattract] of patch-here < energy)
  [ rt random 90 lt random 90
    jump random 3
  ]
  [move-to max-one-of patches in-radius 3 [totalattract]
    ]
  if energy = 0 [die]
end
```

However, **I want to let it wander within 1 tick** - to start with the wandering (jumping) and at the end of jumping (when its `energy < [totalattract]` of patch-here) `move-it` to patch with highest `[totalattract]` value in splotch in-radius X. I was trying to implement the `while` condition or to `repeat`, however for `repeat` I need a specific number of movement and this one depends of turtle's `energy` and patch's `[totalattract]`. How can I deal with? I will really appreciate every help or advises !!

Comment: so please clarify what happens within the tick - it jumps and looks around. If it happens to have landed on a patch with totalattract > its own energy, then it does a random jump. If it happens to have landed on a patch with a lower totalattract, it jumps to the highest totalattract it can see. Does all this jumping use up energy? The reason I ask is because you have a death test in the above code. You want it to wander within one tick - what is the condition at which it will stop wandering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want **all** of the turtles to do their procedures in 1 tick you want to put the `tick` statement inside your `go` procedure. Like this:

```
to go
   ask turtles [move-turtles]
   ;Some other code here...
   tick
end
```

If you want only one turtle to do its procedure in 1 tick you want to put the `tick` statement inside your `move-tutle` procedure. Like this:

```
to move-turtles
  ifelse ([totalattract] of patch-here < energy)
  [ rt random 90 lt random 90
    jump random 3
  ]
  [move-to max-one-of patches in-radius 3 [totalattract]
    ]
  if energy = 0 [die]
  tick 
end
```

Comment: hi @DavidMerinos thank you for answer I learn how to correctly use ticks !! :) however, I wanted to let all turtles move and look for suitable patch (thus repeat or loop movement) to complete it in only one tick. tgus not to influence timing of their action but force them to produce all movement until succesfuly find patch

Comment: @maycca Then the first solution will do what you want.